# Result on projection map of direct products

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G = A\times B$ and suppose that $U \leq G$ with $N_G(U) = (A\cap N_G(U) \times (B \cap N_G(U))$. I'm not sure if the result $\pi_{A \cap N_G(U)}(U) = \pi_A(U)$, where $\pi$ represents the projection maps.

Here's my attempt: Let $x \in \pi_{A \cap N_G(U)}(U)$ then $x = \pi_{A \cap N_G(U)}(g)$ for some $g\in U$. Now $U \leq N_G(U)$ so $g = (a, b)$ where $a\in A\cap N_G(U)$ and $b \in B \cap N_G(U)$. Then, $x =\pi_{A \cap N_G(U)}((a,b)) = a$. Now $\pi_A((a,b)) = a = x \in \pi_A(U)$. So $\pi_{A \cap N_G(U)}(U) \subseteq \pi_A(U)$

Let $x\in \pi_A(U)$. Then $x = \pi_A(g)$ where $g\in U$. So again $g = (a, b)$ where $a\in A\cap N_G(U)$ and $b \in B \cap N_G(U)$. Now $x = \pi_A((a,b)) = a$ and since $\pi_{A \cap N_G(U)}((a,b)) = a =x$, we have that $x \in \pi_{A \cap N_G(U)}(U)$

Can someone verify if this is correct.

Comment: Hint: The factor groups $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic to the subgroups of elements of the form $(a,e_B)$ and $(e_A,b)$ respectively. Those subgroups are normal subgroups of $G$, hence the relevant projection maps can be extended (by isomorphism) to a homomorphism between $G$ and either factor $A$ or $B$.

Comment: @JustinBenfield Can you verify the part that I have added on to make my proof complete?

Comment: The more I stare at the definition given for $N_G(U)$ the more I don't like it. It's abusing notation, because $N_G(U)$ is a set of $(a,b)$'s that live in $G$ whereas $A$ is the set of $a$'s in $A$. What they have omitted is that $A$ and $B$ here should actually be $A\times \{ e_B\}$ and $\{ e_A\}\times B$. In the definition of $N_G(U)$

Comment: I totally understand what you are saying. I was a bit unsure how the elements in that intersection would look unless you identify them as ordered pairs. More importantly without considering the abuse of notation, is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, everything looks correct to me.